# Problems using jQuery in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I am new to mobile app development (I have some experience with website development). I am trying to use phonegap to build an app that will basically manage inventory. I am trying to add animations using JS and I thought I had installed the jQuery mobile framework, but maybe I did it wrong (I also added a link in the html to the online jquery source). When I try to use the function element.fadeOut();, I get an error that "fadeout is not a function". I also can't seem to use ajax for anything. Super confused about how to use these resources! Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

I tried using the CLI commands for phonegap to install jQuery mobile. I also tried adding the following links to my html:

script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"

```
    var header = document.getElementById("type-header");
var oldHeader = header.innerHTML;
header.fadeOut();
header.innerHTML = newHeader;
header.fadeIn();
```

I want it to make the header fade out, change content, and then fade back in. But more importantly, I want to be able to use jQuery and ajax. I need them for many other important things like communication between the mobile app and a cloud-based SQL database. Please help!! Thanks!!!! :)

Comment: fadeOut and fadeIn work on jQuery objects, not HTML elements ... document.getElementById returns a HTML element ... $('#id') returns a jQuery object .... ``var header = $("#type-header");
var oldHeader = header.html();
header.fadeOut();
header.html(newHeader);
header.fadeIn();``

Comment: Thanks so much! I actually just realized that a couple hours ago and literally face-palmed lol. jQuery is working fine I'm just a complete newb. Making great progress now! Thanks thanks!!